# How do you assign IP to WSL2 and/or Docker container so it can be accessed from local network

Tags: sql-server, docker, wsl-2

I have a host machine (192.168.1.5) which is running Windows 10 with WSL2 (winver 2004 OS build 19041.329).

I've moved my Docker script over to WSL2 (runs fine on a Linux vm) and I have that running fine. I just can not access mssql from either the host machine or anything on my local network.

This is my create script

```
sudo docker run -d \
-p 7000:1433 \
-e SA_PASSWORD=<hidden> \
-e ACCEPT_EULA=Y \
-e MSSQL_PID=Developer \
-v /home/docker/mssql/backup:/data \
-v /home/docker/mssql:/var/opt/mssql \
-e attach_dbs="[{'dbName':'THEDB','dbFiles':['/data/thedb.mdf','/data/thedb_log. ldf']}]" \
--name sql microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest \
```

It works and I can connect into it and query etc from within the image.

I have tried various --network options such as host and bridge.
I'm unsure if this is a docker issue or a WSL2 issue, although I've done a WSL2 sudo apt update fine. I think it uses nat to access the Internet for that. It can't ping any machines on the network. (from WSL2)

How do I configure a public IP (ipv4) such that I can access the mssql database remotely.

Comment: are you using the correct port from host `7000`?

Comment: Yes, I've no problems with the port when connecting to docker on vm from host or remote. WSL2 networking seems different. Its the whole not having a public IP that seems to be stopping access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was not doing anything wrong. The way to access the WSL2 based docker image is by using the host IP address and the port (in my case I had changed the port to 7000).

A few weeks after I posted my question, an update to WSL2 and/or Docker seemed to fix my networking issues, so I can only assume there was a temporary bug being experienced. This issue resolved itself on the two machines I was experiencing the networking issues.